# Sub query with count

Tags: mysql

This query works fine and I get a list of (Male,Female) items.

```
SELECT dmg.dmg_Sex
FROM Demographic dmg
JOIN LINK lnk ON lnk.lnk_dmgID = dmg.dmg_ID
JOIN Admission adm ON adm.adm_ID = lnk.lnk_admID
WHERE adm.adm_ID in (SELECT DISTINCT(adm.adm_ID)
                     FROM Admission adm
                     JOIN LINK lnk ON lnk.lnk_admID = adm.adm_ID
                     JOIN DAILY_LINK dlnk ON dlnk.dlk_lnkID = lnk.lnk_ID
                     WHERE  dlnk.dlk_AssessDate >= '2011/01/01' AND dlnk.dlk_AssessDate <= '2011/03/31')
```

If I do this I get the Male, Female result in a counted list

```
SELECT dmg.dmg_Sex, COUNT (dmg.dmg_Sex)
FROM Demographic dmg
JOIN LINK lnk ON lnk.lnk_dmgID = dmg.dmg_ID
JOIN Admission adm ON adm.adm_ID = lnk.lnk_admID
WHERE adm.adm_ReferralDate >= '2011/01/01'
AND adm.adm_ReferralDate <= '2011/03/31'
GROUP BY dmg.dmg_Sex DESC
```

But trying to combine the two queries by just adding `COUNT (dmg.dmg_Sex)` to the first query does not work. Why is this or am I missing something

```
SELECT dmg.dmg_Sex, COUNT (dmg.dmg_Sex)
FROM Demographic dmg
JOIN LINK lnk ON lnk.lnk_dmgID = dmg.dmg_ID
JOIN Admission adm ON adm.adm_ID = lnk.lnk_admID
WHERE adm.adm_ID in (SELECT DISTINCT(adm.adm_ID)
                     FROM Admission adm
                     JOIN LINK lnk ON lnk.lnk_admID = adm.adm_ID
                     JOIN DAILY_LINK dlnk ON dlnk.dlk_lnkID = lnk.lnk_ID
                     WHERE  dlnk.dlk_AssessDate >= '2011/01/01' AND dlnk.dlk_AssessDate <= '2011/03/31')
```

**Desired output**

> Male     243
>   Female   183

**Output getting now**

> Male
>   Male
>   Male
>   Male
>   Male
>   Male
>   Female
>   Female
>   Female
>   Female
>   Female
>   Female
>   Female

Comment: what is your desired output? first query gives one row per record while second one results only two rows with count of total records. please post a sample output how you want your data look like.

Comment: don't you want to group your combined query? or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: and what the output you are getting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to count sex you need to do the following SQL to your combine SQL

```
GROUP BY dmg.dmg_Sex DESC
```

Comment: Thanks you are correct as-well, but @Crazy2crack was slightly quicker on the draw. Upvoted anyway.

Comment: no worries @morne, the answer was posted in the comments

Answer (score 1):

U should group by `dmg.dmg_Sex` . because if you are using an Aggregate Function in the SELECT clause, it is mandatory to have all the non-aggregate fields in the SELECT clause to be there in the GROUP BY clause.